# How to preserve then action for route pop when replacing routes?

Tags: flutter

So question is a little strange, but I'll try my best to make it clear.

So we have 3 pages:

1. page with list of customers
2. customer info page
3. customer edit page

The flow is
you tap on customer in list
-> router.push(CustomerInfo).then(_refreshList())
and on Customer Info page we have Edit Customer button which goes to CustomerEdit page like
-> router.replace(CustomerEdit)

how can I specify that after poping the CustomerEdit screen and returning to CustomersList Page refresh function goes off?

Comment: So, you want to reflect the action that you just did on edit page over the list page. If I am correct, I think Its more of global state management issue than a route issue. You should use global state management packages for instance provider to do so.

Comment: @nibukdk93 Not really, I am intending to call a refresh action of listController on first page, when i get back to it. Something like that.

Comment: Use provider package with change notifier listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a function after popping works like so:

```
Navigator.push().then(functiontThatShouldBeExecuted);
```